# find position of an element relative to latest relative positioned parent with javascript

Tags: javascript, position

Is There any way to find an element position related to latest relative position parent?

I want a javascript way

assume we have this HTML

```
<div id="div1" style="position:relative"> 
   <div id="div2" style="padding:10px">
      <div id="div3" style="position:absolute top:15px; left:20px;">Stack</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want position of "div3" related to "div1".

Thanks

Comment: You want to find the x/y coordinates of `div3` in relation to `div1`?

Comment: I assume you have tried `.position()`? http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: yes David, To solve a problem That there is in [niceform](http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/)

Comment: @FelixKling, Is there any java script way? I prefer not to use jQuery

Comment: Ops, I saw it tagged jQuery for some reason :) In any case, you can have look at the source code for this function. It will give you a cross-browser solution (jQuery is JavaScript too ;)), though it might be a bit over the top.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`div3.offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) and [`div3.offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetleft) should fit your requirement(s).

Comment: Hi Xander, Is it work in all browsers? [Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html) it says:

"Before going to the tricky bits, first a nice shortcut that has been inserted into both Mozilla and Explorer: offsetSomething."

Comment: @Mosijava as @pimvdb just pointed out - it is quirky in IE <= 7. This will work for your scenario. If you want the position of the element relative to the document, then you'll need a method to `add` the offsets of all parents. Similar to the method similar to the one discussed in the following post http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html